# Is there any possibility to missing objects after they are returned from the Skelton in Axis2 WS - java

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, stub

Currently I'm working on the Web Service project built on Axis2.
In there, when I add a log to the server code to print the length of a particular object (before the Skelton returns the output), it prints it correctly.

But when I add the same code to the client once I received, it gives a null pointer. (OTA_VehAvailRateRSSequence_type0 is null in the below exaple)

```
OTA_VehAvailRateRS oTA_VehAvailRateRS =  stub.CarSearch(oTA_VehAvailRateRQ);
VehicleVendorAvailabilityType[] vehicleVendorAvailabilityTypes = oTA_VehAvailRateRS.getOTA_VehAvailRateRSChoice_type0().getOTA_VehAvailRateRSSequence_type0() .getVehAvailRSCore().getVehVendorAvails().getVehVendorAvail();
logger.info("buildResponse().vehicleVendorAvailabilityTypes.length : " + vehicleVendorAvailabilityTypes.length);
```

What could be the reason for this?
Is there any possibility to missing the objects after they are returned from the Skelton .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a sequence type is nested in side a choice type here that could trigger this, OTA xsd types are much complex and can curse this kind of issues when working with Axis2 but i don't think that it's related to Axis2 but this could be a issue with non-standard xsd type definition, you could try removing ether nested sequence type or choice type from the xsd and also remember to have same xsd/wsdl on both client and server side when you do the Axis2 code generation.